# onsen in phonegap is not opening the keyboard

Tags: android, cordova, input, keyboard, onsen-ui

I am building a phonegap onsen.ui application, however I have noticed that on some devices to give focus to an input keyboard does not open for writing.

the device that is not opening the keyboard has android 4.2.2 version, I'm using onsenui - v1.3.8, and phonegap version is 5.3.5

if anyone knows this problem must thank you in advance

Comment: @Juuliancho9191,  you may need to add [fastclick.js](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick). You might be experiencing the 300ms delay.

Comment: Actually fastclick.js is included in Onsen UI by default so I don't think that is the problem.

Does the keyboard open if you have not bootstrapped Onsen UI? What does you HTML look like?